# Trusted and small price 220 to 5V

Tags: power-supply, heat-protection

How do you choose your 220V to 5V components? For example, should I trust one like [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Precision-5V-700mA-3-5W-Isolated-Switching-Power-Supply-AC-DC-Buck-Module-220-to-5V/32828769503.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dely2OJ) that it doesn't heat too much or that it doesn't catch fire?

The component needs to be relatively small priced such that it can be used in production.

Is there something that I can do to verify the quality?

Comment: *For example, should I trust one like this that it doesn't heat too much or that it doesn't catch fire?* That one? Oh no!! Just No. *Is there something that I can do to verify the quality?* Yes, become knowledgeable on the subject, then reverse engineer the item. Maybe get some high voltage test equipment. All in all, it is better to spend a bit more money on something that has safety ratings already.

Comment: If you have no idea how to read a spec , don't buy anything without specs.  ( unless its someone else paying for this lot and they cant hurt you) Specs define things like MTBF, temperature rise, insulation voltage rating and surge protection level.  Don't even think of trying to design one if you have never written a  spec.

Comment: An isolated supply typically has a very clear gap between the traces on the line and secondary sides, under the inductor, with components that have to cross that line, like the optocoupler vsible on the underside left side having a creepage slot cut, to meet the requirements for UL or similar standards, so I'd bet that one, while it may function reliably, likely doesn't meet any standard. As such it's likely that the inductor construction doesn't have the appropriate isolation between the coils either. If you're using these in a product you will need to adhere to standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of very good articles by Ken Shirriff on the subject of cheap power supplies: http://www.righto.com/2014/05/a-look-inside-ipad-chargers-pricey.html / http://www.righto.com/2012/10/a-dozen-usb-chargers-in-lab-apple-is.html ; he discusses the important safety and performance design issues with real examples.

For manufacturing usage, really you have to certify rather than trust. In the US there is UL certification. The EU has CE marking, which doesn't necessarily apply to subassemblies like this but does apply to external "bricks".

Generally almost all designers choose the "brick" option, because then you only have to certify the contents and safety of the brick. Most designs that want 5V use USB micro-B connectors so they can be powered from phone chargers.